# Is is possible to have a callout anywhere on the screen?

Tags: .net, winforms

I have been beating my head over this a few weeks and don't know quite what to do. I have a form which users fill out and save. If anybody comes back into the form and makes a change for example to the first name it will show a callout/tooltip pointing at the control with what the old value used to be. I have all the programming done to detect the changes I am just having issues with the callout/tooltip type thing. I am looking for something that maybe has a line with a label which can point to the object on the screen I am working with. Something like this (doesnt have to be fancy as this)

[image]

However I need it to be movable and basically follow the object around if the user moves the window. Is this even possible? Thanks for any ideas/tips etc.